# Interpolating polyline in Cesium?

Tags: interpolation, cesium

I have a line on map ( actualy is a polyline ) and need to move the camera or an entity model along it.

The examples I've seen uses only path with czml but I need something more simple like divide the line in points at equal distance.

How can I do this?

Comment: https://sandcastle.cesium.com/?src=Interpolation.html Search for "interpola" and there are some useful CZML/Cesium examples